# Lorenzen embedding theorem for an $\ell$-group

Tags: group-theory, commutative-algebra

The Lorenzen embedding theorem for an lattice-ordered group says that any lattice-ordered group can be embedded into a product of totally ordered group. What condition on lattice-ordered group makes this embedding will be an isomorphism? Thanks